# Active 2.0 (or 2.1) speakers for (older) video game consoles

Tags: speakers

I need active speakers. Preferably 2.0, but 2.1 would work, too.

The speakers will sit on a table, right next to a CRT. They will primarily be used for older video game consoles (from SNES to Dreamcast). The players will sit circa 1-2 meters in front of them.

- I would prefer a **cinch/RCA** input (red and white cables). If they don’t have one, I’d need a recommendation for a suitable adapter, too.
- I would like to be able to connect **headphones**. If connected, the speakers should be muted automatically.
- Power plug for Germany.

Budget: I’m hoping for less than 80 € (shipping to Germany).

If multiple sources can be connected via cinch (so no need to manually switch the cables when switching the console) and/or if newer consoles can be connected (optical?), I’d be willing to pay 120 €, or 150 € if they are really good (future-proof, ‎long lifetime).

Comment: I read that it might be preferable not to buy one of those complete sets, but go for an amp (or active subwoofer) and separate passive speakers. I would also be interested in this, so if this is possible within my budget (~ 150 €, or some more if the quality is good, e.g., 180 €), please recommend :)

Answer (score 0):

The [Behringer MS16](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B00181T20O) has the requirements:

[image: Behringer MS16 Manual]